# Compiling OpenJDK 7 with Arch Linux complains about ALSA

Tags: arch-linux, alsa, openjdk

I downloaded [`icedtea2.3.3`](http://icedtea.wildebeest.org/download/source/icedtea-2.3.3.tar.gz) and installed `alsa-lib` `alsa-firmware`,

`./configure` doesn't give any error, but `make` complains that ALSA 0.9.8 or higher is needed.

Actually, ALSA 1.0.25 is installed.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because make cannot find `grep` and `egrep`. The `UNIX_COMMAND_PATH` is pointing to `/bin`, but `grep` and `egrep` are located in `/usr/bin`.

So `make` cannot find the version of file `/usr/include/alsa/version.h`.

Looking into `icedtea-2.3.3/openjdk-boot/jdk/make/common/shared/Defs-linux.gmk`, `UNIX_COMMAND_PATH` can be defined as `ALT_UNIX_PATH`:

```
UNIXCOMMAND_PATH :=$(call PrefixPath,$(ALT_UNIXCOMMAND_PATH))
```

just

```
export ALT_UNIXCOMMAND_PATH=/usr/bin
ln -s /bin/sh /usr/bin/sh
```

Then `make` returns no error. If make complains something not found in /usr/bin/ but it is located in /bin, just make a symbolic link to /bin.

Comment: For me, `export ALT_UNIXCOMMAND_PATH=/usr/bin` was enough. No symlinking was necessary.